# Can i apply normal map & bump map & a texture on the same object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, node-editor

So I have these[image]

[image]

I want to combine them all. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, but i want to know if there is a better way to do it
[image: This seems to work, but i want to know if there is a better way to do it]

Comment: There is a better way. With this method, you are applying the normal map to the glossy reflections, and the bump map to the diffuse. You should combine the normal and bump vectors with vector add node, and then vector normalize node.